# how to use jit spacetree and jqgrid on same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jqgrid

I have one page in which I want jit Spacetree and jqgrid. But it show either jqgrid or Spacetree correctly. I am loading Spacetree with json data by ajax request.
root node never comes, but all other nodes comes and it is fully functional. If I delete jqgrid includes then tree loads with root node. 
I have used this example of spacetree

http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example2.html

I have replaced 3 lines of example2.js with this function

```
 st.loadJSON(eval(  $.parseJSON(json)));
st.compute();
st.onClick(st.root);
```

function to get json data

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../default.aspx",
       data: {Mode: 'Tree'},
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(response) {
              var response = $.parseJSON(response);

                  //load json data
                   st.loadJSON(response);

                    //compute node positions and layout
                    st.compute();
                    //optional: make a translation of the tree
                  //  st.geom.translate(new $jit.Complex(-200, 0), "current");
                    //emulate a click on the root node.
                    st.onClick(st.root);
                   // NodeId=st.root;

        },
        error: function(rs, e) {
               //alert(rs.responseText);
               return false;
        }
  });
```

I have used this jqgrid

http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/yNw3C/

I have included following files in html

- jqgrid-4.4.5-src/ui.jqgrid.css,
- jqgrid-4.4.5-src/jquery.jqGrid.js,
- jqgrid-4.4.5-src/jquery-ui.css,
- jqgrid-4.4.5-src/grid.locale-en.js,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of naming convention used by jqgrid and spacetree. Both were creating same id.  jqgrid was creating a row with the id =1 and spacetree was also creating a div with id=1. Now while creating nodes of the tree, dom was fetching the div by id. As jqgrid was loading first so dom was getting the id of the jqgrid row instead of div. I changed the jqgrid id-creation process by adding prefix to it. And now it is working.